# Notification emails/ news feeds, can they be customized?

Tags: 2013, social

I am using the new webpart Sitefeed, and people is starting to interact with it!

However our intranet is orange, but the notification emails received come with blue links. I wonder if there is a way to change this notification to look like our intranet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.
E-mails are formed in internal SharePoint libraries, and mail text and colors are hardcoded.

Some explanations and technical details:

If you open html source of any of this e-mails, you'll see `style` tag with content

`a { color: #0072bc; text-decoration: none; }`

You can just search this text with reflector in SP assemblies. This style tag is created in `Microsoft.Office.Server.Email.SPMailMessageHelper.GetSocialNotificationMailMessage` method:

`stringBuilder.Append("a { color: #0072bc; text-decoration: none; }");`

So, link colors and all email text are set in C# code, and you can not change them.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer you have several ways to customize the alerts.

In order to insert your company's logo, you will have to implement your own iAlertNotifyHandler.

You can get an overview about your possibilities here: "msdn Library > Alerts in SharePoint Foundation"

The article says nothing about SharePoint 2013, but when you look in the documentation for "msdn Library > SharePoint schemas > AlertTemplates schema", you'll find that it still works with SharePoint 2013.

Here are two tutorials that should help you:

- [How to: How To: Customizing alert emails using
  IAlertNotifyHandler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx)
- [SharePoint 2010 custom alert template](http://blog.zebsadiq.com/post/SharePoint-2010-custom-alert-template.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Step by step guide is provided here. [Here](http://sharepointrealm.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-cusomize-alert-email-for.html)

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)